# I want to add First name and last name field

Tags: django, django-forms

My form only gives me username, email, password1, password2, i wanna have First name and Last name on this firl too.

My form:

```
    <div class="col-12">
            <h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

            <p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

            <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form|crispy }}
              {% if redirect_field_value %}
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
              {% endif %}
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
            </form>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can define your custom form to render with specific fields

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1','password2')
```

Comment: i am new at programming im sorry, it says User is not defined what should i do next please, do i need a user model or?

Comment: You have to import User model - from django.contrib.auth.models import User. I have made changes accordingly in my answer.